# NTP does not update until after I poll it

Tags: linux, ntp, time, gps

I have NTP setup to run with GPSd and all is well. The issue arises after about a week of my raspberry pi being disconnected, NTP will trust the old date on the system clock. Since the GPS takes a couple seconds to get power and acquire a lock it seems like NTP will trust my local clock and never check the GPS again.

Interestingly if I run `ntpq -p` I see:

```
SHM(0)     .GPS.  0 l  -  16  0  0.000  0.000  0.000
*LOCAL(0)  .LOCL. 10 l 45  64  377  0.000  0.000  0.001
```

Then running the exact same command immediately after:

```
*SHM(0)     .GPS.  0 l  1  16  0  0.000  9516243  0.001
LOCAL(0)  .LOCL. 10 l 45  64  377  0.000  0.000  0.001
```

For some reason, although the GPS was online and reporting time, NTP never tried polling it again until after I ran `ntpq -p`

My config is as follows:

```
# WARNING: Disabling the panicgate is insecure when you don't fully trust your time calibrations. Since we are
# only using a GPS, this is okay.
tinker panic 0

# Permit time synchronization with our time source, but do not
# permit the source to query or modify the service on this system.

restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer

# Permit all access over the loopback interface. This could
# be tightened as well, but to do so would effect some of
# the administrative functions.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict -6 ::1

# Only allow on our own network
restrict 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap

# Read the rough GPS time from device 127.127.28.0
# Read the accurate PPS time from device 127.127.28.1
# The flag1 will allow skipping the time difference, see driver28 in NTP documentation:
# https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/drivers/driver28.html
server 127.127.28.0 minpoll 4 maxpoll 4 iburst prefer
fudge 127.127.28.0 time1 0.535 refid GPS flag1 1

# Local clock backup
server 127.127.1.0 # local clock
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10

# Use servers from the ntp pool for the first synchronization,
# or as a backup if the GPS is disconnected
server 0.pool.ntp.org
server 1.pool.ntp.org
server 2.pool.ntp.org
server 3.pool.ntp.org

# Ignore all other interfaces but itself
interface ignore wildcard
interface listen 127.0.0.1
interface listen ::1

# Drift file. Put this in a directory which the daemon can write to.
# No symbolic links allowed, either, since the daemon updates the file
# by creating a temporary in the same directory and then rename()’ing
# it to the file.
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
logfile /var/log/ntp.log
statsdir /var/log/ntp/
statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats

filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm almost at the point of just having a cronjob run the command every so often so it gives the GPS a chance to respond.

Comment: You may need to wait longer. The 7th field is reachability and it is 0 for SHM(0). It is a rolling window counter and the maximum is 377 (reachable evert time).

Comment: Thanks @MarkWagner, is there anyway to decrease the amount of time it takes for it to be polled again? I thought that would be covered by the maxpoll option I have in my config.

Comment: @Chaos the offset of 9516243 might have something to do with it... can you leave it running a while then post the output from `ntpq -pcrv` please. Also you say your using GPS, but what NMEA or PPS or both?